# How to catch when a promise fails?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, error-handling, zapier

#### Problem

My code is searching the database for a record and returns error when it cannot find an existing entry. It needs to check if the request is empty before parsing and return an empty array if it did not find a record and return [results] array if it does find one. How do I solve this problem?

This is for a Zapier integration with Zoho CRM that will search a custom module by `Account_Name` for an existing record and create one if it does not already exist.

#### Code

```
const options = {
  url: `https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/Accounts/search?criteria=(Account_Name:equals:${bundle.inputData.Account_Name})`,
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Zoho-oauthtoken ${bundle.authData.access_token}`,
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  },
  params: {

  }
}

return z.request(options)
  .then((response) => {
    response.throwForStatus();
    const results = [z.JSON.parse(response.content)];
    return [results];
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using a `catch` if your promise fails to resolve.

Like:

```
return z.request(options)
  .then((response) => {
    response.throwForStatus();
    const results = [z.JSON.parse(response.content)];
    return [results];
  })
  .catch(err => {
     /* 
      check if the error is specifically where no entry in db was found.
       Or if the error is always for that purpose
     */
     console.log(err) // handle error approriately, maybe send to sentry?
     return []; //emtpy array, when db errors out?
   });
```

Comment: Thank you so much omkar! Your solution was spot on! I've been trying for days to get the code right. I should have posted this question a while ago! The catch worked perfect to return the empty array needed to allow the rest of the code to create a record. Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

if response.content is null when it doesn't find anything:

```
.then((response) => {
   ...
   return (response.content) ? 
   [z.JSON.parse(response.content)] : 
   Error("invalid request");
}
```

if response.content is an empty object when it doesn't find anything:

```
.then((response) => {
  ...
  return (Object.keys(response.content).length) ? 
  [z.JSON.parse(response.content)] 
  : Error("invalid request");
}
```